# Remember ng-grid grouping open||collapsed states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

The ng-grid has the gridoption "showGroupPanel" which allows you to d&d a columnheader in your grid and sort your content by that column.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43}
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        showGroupPanel: true
    };
});
```

See example here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Bo11ckeWFiMyJ4tyLVWC?p=preview

In my application I would like the open||closed property of each group to be stored in local storage, and used when the page is reloaded. Is there a property for the groups or has anyone been able to solve this in some other way?

Answer (score 2):

There are properties for these. I found them here:

$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.renderedRows[].collapsed= true or false
and 
$scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.configGroups contains the grouping column info

Comment: Great thank you! Took some fiddling but worked it out in the end. 

Catched the group-toggle-event by adding a custom aggregateTemplate. Then saved each group collapse-state in webStorage and looped trough the groups and set the state when ng-grid was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First of I wan't to give credit to Imyers previous response, it led me on the right track. Anyhow:

You can access each group in the grid by:

```
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.rowFactory.aggCache
```

Each group has a collapse-value of true|false

When the user open or collapses a group I was able to catch the event by adding a custom aggregateTemplate on my gridOptions:

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: "myData",
    showGroupPanel: true,
    aggregateTemplate: 
    "<div ng-click='row.toggleExpand(); saveGroupState()' ng-style='rowStyle(row)' class='ngAggregate ng-scope' style='top: 0px; height: 48px; left: 0px;'>"+
        "<span class='ngAggregateText ng-binding'>"+
            "{{row.label CUSTOM_FILTERS}} ({{row.totalChildren()}} {{AggItemsLabel}})"+
        "</span>"+
        "<div ng-class="{true: 'ngAggArrowCollapsed', false: 'ngAggArrowExpanded'}[row.collapsed]"></div>"+
    "</div>"
}
```

The saveGroupState() function then saves each rows collapse-state in localStorage based on the rows Label

```
$scope.saveGroupState = function () {
   var groups = $scope.gridOptions.$gridScope.renderedRows;
   for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem("taskListGroup_" + groups[i].label, groups[i].collapsed);
   }
}
```

Now you have the states of your groups save in localStorage and a function that catches the toggle event and updating that value.

Next step is to simply compare the initial collapse state with your value in localstorage when the ng-grid has loaded and toggle the row if necessary using:

```
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.rowFactory.aggCache[rowIndex].toggleExpand();
```

I realize there are many ways to optimize this, I was simply looking for a way to quickly make it work, a poc.

Ideas for improvements are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in this way Please have a look if this is convenient for you.

Please go to the ng-grid.js and make *groupsCollapsedByDefault* to false.

Now if you refresh the grid in that case the grid status will remains the same (collapsed grid will be collapsed and expanded grid will remain expanded.)

Thank you. I hope this helps, Chess !!